# Converting CassandraTableScanRDD org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, cassandra, rdd

I have a following situation. I have large Cassandra table (with large number of columns) which i would like process with Spark.  I want only selected columns to be loaded in to Spark ( Apply select and filtering on Cassandra server itself)

```
 val eptable = 
 sc.cassandraTable("test","devices").select("device_ccompany","device_model","devi
 ce_type")
```

Above statement gives a CassandraTableScanRDD but how do i convert this in to DataSet/DataFrame ?

Si there any other way i can do server side filtering of columns and get dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

In DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector, you would read Cassandra data as a `Dataset`, and prune columns on the server-side as follows:

```
val df = spark
 .read
 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
 .options(Map( "table" -> "devices", "keyspace" -> "test" ))
 .load()

val dfWithColumnPruned = df
 .select("device_ccompany","device_model","device_type")
```

Note that the `selection` operation I do after reading is pushed to the server-side using Catalyst optimizations. Refer this [document](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) for further information.